# Pinterest endpoint not giving json data

Tags: python, web-scraping, pinterest

So I have a endpoint that returns the json data that hold pin info when you search for a keyword, but when I request it directly through the browser. It just brings me to the "this page does not exist" page on pinterest. How can I return the json data??

heres the url:
https://www.pinterest.ca/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Fq%3D%2523yee%26rs%3Dtyped%26term_meta%5B%5D%3D%2523yee%257Ctyped&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22filters%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22%23yee%22%2C%22rs%22%3A%22typed%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1512061334641

code:

```
def pinterestTagFetch():
    username = "" #username = sys.argv[1]
    password = "" #password = sys.argv[2]
    url = "https://www.pinterest.ca/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Fq%3D%2523yee%26rs%3Dtyped%26term_meta%5B%5D%3D%2523yee%257Ctyped&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22filters%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22%23yee%22%2C%22rs%22%3A%22typed%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1512061334641"
    loginUrl = "https://www.pinterest.ca/login"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(loginUrl)
    usernameEntry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[1]/div/input")
    passwordEntry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[2]/div/input")
    loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/button")
    usernameEntry.send_keys(username)
    passwordEntry.send_keys(password)
    loginButton.click()
    driver.get(url)
    os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you.

Comment: Just a basic login right now but from here I don't really know how to get the data I'm looking for @AttoAllas

Comment: The `url` link seems to be wrong itself, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @AttoAllas I just noticed that wups, changed it

Comment: Is this url login specific? Because it seems to still be wrong on my end. I'll try to figure out the problem

Comment: @AttoAllas I know the new one is the correct one, because that's the exact same url that my browser requests when I search something on pinterest

Comment: @AttoAllas No its not :(

Comment: Because if I decode it the query looks like this

Comment: https://www.pinterest.ca/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=/search/pins/?q=#yee&rs=typed&term_meta[]=#yee|typed&data={"options":{"filters":null,"query":"#yee","rs":"typed","scope":"pins"},"context":{}}&_=1512061334641

Comment: I think your program is having the same problem I am, have you tried the [pintrest api?](https://developers.pinterest.com/). This could yield better results for you.

Comment: @AttoAllas I have but they got rid of the search endpoint :(

Comment: I think that the url you are putting in only works for your specific session of your specific browser, meaning that you are going to have to generate that url within the program in order to get it to work. You have shown that you can use the webdriver module, so why not just use that to type into the search box and then click the search button, then get the source?